Pimcore/Symfony Bundle with custom token authentication for custom controller
I am completely struggling to get a custom bundle in Pimcore working as expected. I have a controller in this bundle that must be secured by a token authentication (like a Bearer token). This is my security.yml in BUNDLE_DIR/Resources/config/security.yml:
security:
providers:
    noop_user_provider:
        id: MyVendor\PimcoreApiBundle\Security\NoopUserProvider

firewalls:
    api:
        pattern:   ^/api
        stateless: true
        guard:
            authenticators:
                - MyVendor\PimcoreApiBundle\Security\TokenAuthenticator

access_control:
    - { path: ^/api, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_FULLY }

My controller route is as follows (via annotations):
/**
 * @param string $id
 * @return JsonResponse
 * @Route("/api/read/{id}", name="myvendor_pimcore_api_read", methods={"GET"})
 */
public function read(string $id): JsonResponse
{
    return $this->json([
        'message' => 'Hello from your custom API! You ID was: '.$id,
    ]);
}

And my services.yml (directory: BUNDLE_DIR/Resources/config/services.yml) has the following entry:
    MyVendor\PimcoreApiBundle\Security\TokenAuthenticator:
    arguments:
        $validToken: 'sampleToken123'
    tags:
        - { name: security.guard_authenticator }

And whatever I tried, I cannot get it to work. If I try to include my security.yml via DependencyInjection, I get an error:
public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container): void
{
    $configuration = new Configuration();
    $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

    $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
    $loader->load('services.yml');
    $loader->load('security.yaml');
}

I get this error: There is no extension able to load the configuration for "security" (in "/var/www/html/bundles/MyVendor/PimcoreApiBundle/DependencyInjection/../Resources/config/security.yaml"). Looked for namespace "security", found "none".
I also tried multiple other things, which all resulted in more or less the same issue. Can someone help me here? I just want to my controller to be secured...

Is your security.yml formatted the same way as described? If this is indeed the case, it may be due to wrong indents, as "security" is a key without any values. Also you may want to check the file extensions, sometimes you wrote yml and sometimes yaml, so just make sure those match. Other than that I couldn't really see anything else really wrong here.
